# DBF file parallel reading

Tags: c++, visual-foxpro, foxpro, dbf

A foxpro software reads , writes and updates records in a DBF file. I parallely read that same DBF in a c++ application. Will there be any issues if I keep my c++ applications reading DBF file for a long time ?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the DBF format is multi-user -- nearly every real-world application that uses them is multi-user; we have apps used by hundreds of users for example.

There may be a problem in that your C++ application does not respect the locking mechanism that FoxPro would use, but that's not the same thing. If you use Microsoft Visual FoxPro OLEDB driver properly on the C++ side you won't have an issue, but yes as with anything like this open and close the DBF as quickly as you can.

Answer (score 0):

VFP tables are file based and use shared lock while updating it. If you are doing reading it directly (low level), with only reading there wouldn't be a problem. Since it is data anyway and the best optimised readers are OLEDB\ODBC drivers (ODBC drivers exist for up to version 6. For later versions, Sybase Advantage Server has a driver -local free, remote paid AFAIK but I don't use).

I have been using DBF tables from VFP (yes from VFP) and C# via VFPOLEDB for a long time and I can say I had no issues. Actually, the driver works better from C# vs from within VFP, I don't know why.

Also note that, when you are using VFPOLEDB driver, you are using ANSI mode by default (and shared for read\write unless you change the mode).

Answer (score 0):

If you keep the DBF file open for a long time, you prevent data structure updates to the table. If the VFP application is updated and needs new columns in the DBF file that you are reading, the update would fail until your program stops.

To fix this you or your client would need to change the update process to include your application.

Sometimes VFP applications contain a mechanism that terminates the application. Usually this is some sort of timer that checks a specific field or some file, and then terminates the application. This is often used, because users keep applications open when the leave work. The database is therefore still locked impacting updates and sometimes consistent backups.

You can fix this by implementing the same mechanism in your application.